# Cannot convert character array to wstring with utf-8 characters

Tags: c++, visual-c++, utf-8, wstring

When I tried to convert char* to wstring using below function in Visual C++.The function is able to convert strings in normal english language, but when I use characters from other language, it is not converting all the characters.

```
std::wstring s2ws(const char* utf8Bytes)
{
    const std::string& str(utf8Bytes);
    int size_needed = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), NULL, 0);
    std::wstring wstrTo(size_needed, 0);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), &wstrTo[0], size_needed);
    return wstrTo;
}
```

Example:
When I'm printing the converted value into MessageBox, Grüßen is shown as Gr??en

I'm using this converted wstring for obtaining the contents of my directory like below:

```
map<wstring, wstring> getAllFiles(wstring folder, wstring filter) {  
    wstring directory = folder + L"/" + filter;
    WCHAR szBuf[MAX_PATH];
    WIN32_FIND_DATA d;
    HANDLE hFindFile = FindFirstFile(directory.c_str(), &d);
    .....
}
```

Here I'm not getting an expected output. i.e., the contents of the directory. But getting it when utf8bytes array is normal English characters.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why `const std::string& str(utf8Bytes)` instead of the "natural" `std::string str = utf8bytes;`? Why the temporary `str` variable in the first place, it's not needed. You can just use `utf8bytes` and `strlen(utf8bytes)` (UTF-8 encoded characters will never contain a zero byte).

Comment: How are you checking the conversion?  I ask because this can be a source of false errors.

Comment: I'm printing to MessageBox in Visual C++.

Comment: Actually this code is part of a library I'm creating and what I get through function parameter is char*.

Comment: If `utfBytes` is terminated (it certainly better be, as the conversion constructor for `std::string` you're using requires it), you can just pass it and `-1` for the length to MB2WC. It will convert up to (and through) the terminating nullchar. In short, you don't need `str` at all, and can even avoid `strlen` as well.

Comment: To isolate the problem better, print both strings as a sequence of hex character codes.

Comment: Updated the question with some context

Comment: @KrishnakumarCN What does the code that is calling `s2ws()` look like?  Where is the input data coming from exactly? Are you SURE the input data is really encoded in UTF-8? The failure you describe suggests that the input data is NOT encoded in UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change code to below:

```
std::wstring s2ws(const char* utf8Bytes)
{
    const std::string& str(utf8Bytes);
    int size_needed = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), NULL, 0);
    std::wstring wstrTo(size_needed, 0);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), &wstrTo[0], size_needed);
    return wstrTo;
}
```

Difference between two flags is listed [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24280030/MultiByteToWideChar.html).

Comment: `CP_ACP` != `CP_UTF8`.  If the input *IS* UTF-8, DO NOT use `CP_ACP`. If the input *IS NOT* UTF-8, DO NOT use `CP_UTF8`, and the naming of the input parameter is misleading.

Comment: This solution is good based on the description, but as @Remy says, the parameter name should be changed from `utf8Bytes` to something else (like `ansiBytes`). You are getting the values in the `ACP` (= Active Code Page) which is almost never UTF8 Windows. (You can enable UTF8 as your code page, but then `CP_ACP` still works just fine).

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is doing the right thing and the problem must be with your UTF-8 string. If I call your code like this, it works as expected:

```
char utf8buffer[1024];

WideCharToMultiByte(
    CP_UTF8,
    WC_ERR_INVALID_CHARS,
    L"Grüßen",
    -1,
    utf8buffer,
    1024,
    nullptr,
    false
);

assert(s2ws(utf8buffer) == L"Grüßen");
```